# Can a person say the bracha for thunder if he hasn't seen the lightning?

Tags: halacha, blessing, weather

Can someone say the bracha upon hearing thunder without having seen the lightning bolt (in any form, i.e. he didn't notice any light at all?) Scientifically, lightning causes the thunder. (Most of the time. I'm not factoring how far the listener is from the bolt.)

So, if someone hears thunder, can he assume that there was lightning, automatically? Or should we reason that since there are sounds similar to thunder, the person needs to be sure that this was actually thunder?

Comment: Even if he saw lightning how could he be sure it was thunder that followed?

Comment: The converse case: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1944

Answer (score 2):

The Mishna Brurah 227:5 writes :

על כל אחד וכו' - והעולם נוהגים לברך על הברקים עושה מ"ב ועל הרעמים שכחו וגבורתו וכו' וכן מסתבר שע"י הרעם נראה גבורתו של הקב"ה יותר מבברק אמנם באמת שייך כל אחת מהברכות על שניהם וע"כ אם שמע ברק ורעם כאחד מברך ברכה אחת דהיינו עושה מע"ב על שניהם ואם בירך שכחו וגבורתו מ"ע ג"כ יוצא. ואם לא היו תכופים זה אחר זה מברך תחלה על הברק [שהוא מתראה תחלה לעין האדם] עושה מע"ב ואח"כ על הרעם שכחו וגבורתו מ"ע **וה"ה אם לא ראה את הברק ושמע קול הרעם ובירך עליו שכחו וגבורתו מ"ע או שבירך עושה מע"ב ואח"כ ראה ברק מברך עליו ג"כ עושה מע"ב** ועיין בשע"ת שכתב בשם הברכ"י דאם בירך על הברק ונתכוין לפטור הרעם הבא אחריו יצא בדיעבד ור"ל דאחרי שטבע הבריאה שאחר הברק יוצא רעם א"כ חל ברכתו על הרעם שיצא אח"כ:

If one hears thunder first he makes a bracha of shecocho,and if he sees lighting afterwards he makes oseh maaseh bereishes.If they come at the same time one makes an oseh maaseh berieshes.Since lighting one sees first he makes an oseh maaseh and then naturally should hear thunder and then make a shechocho,but if he didn't see lighting then the halacha is like above.(this is not a word for word translation just the concepts)

Comment: I don't see where he says that someone who hears thunder before seeing lightning should say "_shekocho_". (I do, however, see where he says what someone should do who did say "_shekocho_" on thunder alone and then saw lightning.)

Comment: That's not how I read it,it seems like that's what one should do,but in normal circumstances one usually sees lighting first