# Can one make a bracha on non-thunderstorm lightning?

Tags: halacha, blessing

Most of us associate lightning with thunderstorms. But there are other ways "lightning" can be caused:

- static discharge such as what you may see when you rub your feet on a rug on a cold dry day, and when touching someone, a spark jumps from your finger. This is a form of lightning.
- The lightning created by those wonderful science machines / experiments shown in museums. (Similar to what you see in Frankenstein movies.)
- [Volcanic lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Dirty_thunderstorm).

Can or should one say the bracha on any of these (and similar) forms of lightning? Why or why not?

Comment: The whole point of the Bracha is עושה מעשה בראשית.

Comment: I was once in a car with a Rebbi of mine and there was some [heat lightening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_lightning), and he said we don't say the Blessing on that. I believe that's why you don't say the blessing on lightening until you've already heard a thunder, and said the blessing on it.

Comment: @Salmononius2 I'm not sure that your rebbe was completely correct. See MB. I'll see if I can locate it, later if u can't find it. IIRC there is machloket.

Comment: @HaLeiVi I'm unclear what you're conveying.

Comment: We make the Bracha Maaseh Bereishis because these things remind us of how Hashem created the world. They are all impressive items, or at least something seldom seen. They are all natural phenomena. You don't make the Bracha on man made items.

Comment: @HaLeiVi Got it. You could argue that static electricity is always present and in itself is a natural phenomena (a "ma'aseh breishit"). If you take the term "Ma'aseh Breishit" literary, we may have to determine if lightning was actually part of the "creation process" itself; there is no mention of it in the Torah in parshat Breishit. That's a whole other question.

Comment: Technically, everything is subject to the laws of physics and therefore "natural," which means that we should make a bracha when we see light refract through a prism (rainbow). Even if the mechanics are "natural" the *process* is man-made. I'm in agreement with @HaLeiVi on this - you'd make it only on naturally occurring lightening (including the volcanic one in your question).

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I agree with you. I was just raising another possibility. The definition of "Ma'aseh Breishit", though, may spur me to another question.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1944/bracha-on-lightning-without-thunder

Answer (score 2):

According to note 34 on 59a3 in the Schottenstein edition of Masechet Brachot,

> "*Rashi* comments that *barka* connotes a flash, a light. His comments
>   may bear upon the view of *Chayei Adam* (cited in *Mishna Berurah*
>   227:3) that lightning arising from heat alone does not warrant a
>   blessing."

The gemara there discusses lightning in the context of clouds so (IMHO) that would also eliminate static discharge and van de graaff generators or tesla coils.

Comment: It seems you have a typo in the 1st sentence, and I can't quite decipher your intent. Please edit. Thanks for providing the scientific name for those Frankenstein machines. Seems that while I was describing them, the lightning zapped my braini :-) If possible, at some point, answer about volcanic lightning. It is in the sky, and the ash is a "cloud", but it is not a typical condensation cloud. I think the mechanics are different from thunderstorm lightning (which BTW, no one completely understands how or why it happens.)

Comment: @DanF I also wasnt clear about what he was saying. After checking that Mishna Berurah I'm guessing that the Artscroll note is trying to say Rashi would disagree with what the Chayei Adam said. That notwithstanding, Danno adding his humble opinion that even Rashi doesn't require a blessing when it's source its from somewhere other than clouds. I would tend to agree with his humble opinion. That's why there is an up vote:)

Comment: @DanF According to this article from Chabad.org quoting the Lubavitcher Rebbe, the blessing for a volcano, which would include the static discharge in the cloud of dust is the same as for thunder (שכחו וגבורתו מלא עולם). http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1192645/jewish/Is-There-a-Blessing-For-a-Volcano.htm

Comment: @rosends Feel free to add the volcano blessing info to your answer if you would like to.

Comment: @rosends See ^^. The bounty ends in 3 days, and I'd be happy to award it!

Comment: @DanF Yaacov has the info which you are looking for. The points belong to him.

Comment: @rosends Unfortunately, I can't split the award. From his comment, I think he's kind enough to give you a gift :-) You can decide to accept or decline his offer. Shabbat Shalom.

Comment: @YaacovDeane It took me a while to read the chabbad article. There is nothing that I noticed, there, that indicates that the blessing made for the volcano itself would include the bracha on its lightning. All it says is "seeing a volcano". The lightning discharge may be considered an effect of the volcano, itself, that might warrant its own blessing for lightning.

Comment: @DanF I was also interested in seeing more detail than what the article offered. I looked up the actual talk with the notes from the Rebbe. Bli neder, when I have the time, I'll post the details. The comment from the Rebbe was sourcing two primary places. Brachot 59b and some kind of discussion in Encyclopedia Talmudit. The gemara, I looked at. Nothing definitive. The Rebbe did say only the blessing of כחו וגבורתו for a volcano. But prior to the volcano mention he talked about both blessings. The omission is notable. I want to track down the ET citation.

Comment: The year was 5751.

Comment: If you are interested, it is in vol. 3 of Torat Menachem from that year. It was for 3rd of Tammuz and the mention is a couple of footnotes. One point worth noting. The Rebbe was fully aware of the static discharges that take place in a volcanic cloud. I'm fairly certain that if שעושה מעשה בראשית was relevant, he would have said it.

Comment: @DanF I was also thinking about the Van DeGraff generator angle. If you consider that we make the blessing for bread, it seems to be a similar circumstance. On that level, the blessing would seem appropriate.

Comment: And what about turning on the electric spark to a gas stove? It's the same situation on a much smaller scale.

Comment: @DanF 1st of all, if you award, it belongs to rosends. 2nd, here is the link to the actual words of the Rebbe from the sicha. http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15977&st=&pgnum=413

Comment: The relevant discussion begins in the text of the sicha at chapter 4. The actual comment dealing with volcanoes is in note 55. It seems from what the Rebbe says that there is a significant discussion about this in Encyclopedia Talmudit in the volume dealing with (ברכות: ערך ברכות הראיה: עמוד  שנו-שנז). I don't have Encyclopedia Talmudit. Something else to put on the shopping list. If anyone has that volume, they might want to help supply the answer for the this question.

Comment: @rosends Please see above two comments to DanF. It may give you a source to fill out your answer.

Comment: @DanF One last important detail. The lightening from volcanoes is different from that of rain clouds in 2 ways. Although both are generated from friction, in rain clouds the friction is from ice particles. In volcanoes, it is primarily from the dust of the eruption. In rain clouds the lightening travels via the ionized plasma in the atmosphere to the ground. In volcanoes, the lightening goes sideways or even upward. It usually doesn't go to ground. That last distinction may be important to the blessing. With raincloud lightning, it travels from above to below all the way to the earth.

Comment: In other words, it follows the model of the act of creation (שעושה מעשה בראשית). That like Moshe Rabbeinu explained to the angels, G-d's ultimate intention with creation was the earth (the Tachtonim). In the case of volcanic lightning, the discharges do not, for the most part, go down to the earth. But they are a manifestation of how G-d's might & power fill all aspects of the universe. (שכחו וגבורתו מלא עולם).

Comment: @DanF Here is an interesting article discussing the most recent research about the differences between volcanic lightning and rain cloud lightning. http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3642674/Volcanoes-really-create-lightning-Mystery-violent-electrical-flashes-ash-clouds-eruptions-solved.html

Comment: If that distinction is the key, then static discharges like heat lightning and  the Van DeGraff generator would fall under the definition of (שכחו וגבורתו מלא עולם).

Answer (score 2):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 60:3 [סימן ס - דין ברכות הראיה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0059_L2) says that lightning caused by heat - that happens without accompanying thunder - are not real lightning and don't warrant a Bracha.

> וְהַבְּרָקִים שֶׁנִּרְאִים בְּלֹא רַעַם אֶלָּא מֵחֲמַת הַחֹם, אֵינָם כִּבְרָקִים מַמָּשׁ וְאֵין מְבָרְכִין עֲלֵיהֶם

He doesn't explain why.

Comment: That would seem to make sense in light of the last  comments I made to rosends answer above. The blessing for lightning would not apply, meaning (שעושה מעשה בראשית). Do you have an Encyclopedia Talmudit? I would love to actually see what the Rebbe points to there on this subject.

Comment: I'd need to read some further commentary on the above paragraph. What is commonly called "heat" lightning does not fit the definition of the Kitzur. Heat lightning is a mistaken name for lightning that is distant such that the thunder cannot be heard in your area. However, heat alone does not cause lightning. It's caused by the differences in polarity between parts of a cloud or between the cloud and the ground. So, a cloud as well as vapor or ice needs to be involved. In short, even "heat lightning" has thunder. It's just that you don't hear it where you are.

Comment: @YaacovDeane See ^^^ for what "heat lightning" really is. You can confirm this definition by Wikipedia, among other sources.

Comment: This may be a case where current science disputes what was known at the time that the Kitzur's halacha was issued. I don't know the exact halachic rules of changing the halacha under such situations.

Comment: @DanF It isn't a matter of changing the halacha. The blessing was fixed by Chazal. Their source is from what they received from Moshe Rabbeinu. The assumption is that what Moshe received from HaShem is correct, meaning the blessing is correct for each circumstance. The problem is that we may not understand, in any given generation, the details of why it applies to a given situation. The more I consider the comments to rosends answer, the more it seems to fit. (Heat lightning notwithstanding. Would have to think about that one more.)

Comment: @DanF According to Wikipedia, Heat Lightning is ordinary raincloud lightning. It is simply very far away from the observer so they do not hear the accompanying thunder. According to their explanation, sound, which is dependent upon the medium of the atmosphere for transmission and echoing off the topography can actually be blocked from traveling great distances. That is not the case, so much, with the light transmission. They also mention Sprite Lightning which is not like Heat Lightning. It does not go to ground and actually occurs above the level of rain clouds.

Comment: Based upon the description of Heat Lightning, since the blessing is dependent upon seeing and not hearing, I would be inclined to say the blessing should be said. The pasak mentioned by Kitzur Shulchan Aruch would seem to be addressing the phenomenon of Sprite Lightning which doesn't go to ground and also doesn't have thunder being heard with it.